# Arguments for OR Opcode in 68000

Tags: disassembly, 68000

I'm having a problem with 68000 assembly language.

The instruction set guide says this:

> The instruction OR performs the logical operation "OR", bit for bit. There
>   are two ways to do this:
>
> 1. The source is an effective address, the destination is a dataregister.
> 2. The source is the dataregister and the destination is the effective address"

But in this:

```
or d0,d6
```

Is d0 the source or the destination? And how can I tell?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of commands in 68k assembly is *command, source, destination*, so in this case the command is `d6 = d0 OR d6`.

Effective addresses don't come into play at all since only data registers are used.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the source, the second the destination; thats *universal* for all two-operand instructions (the only exception IIRC is LINK).

Effective address (aka EA) can be *anything* that fits the instruction; thus Dn *is* a valid EA.

The 68k instruction set is not completely orthogonal (not every addressing mode is allowed anywhere), it  generally provides either EA,Rn or Rn,EA instructions. To make the ISA somewhat orthogonal, many instructions have multiple variants, like the two variants of OR you found. The CPU treats these as different instructions (they are encoded differently).